# Footer sticky at bottom, content-wrapper fill free space

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a web layout:

1. header and footer should be full-width, content narrow and centered
2. footer at the bottom of the screen or at the bottom of the page, depending on content length
3. if the content does not fill the complete screen, its wrapper should fill the screen anyway

[image: Layout as described above]

The first two points are no problem, but by now I can stretch the body only using Javascript. CSS `min-height: 100%` does not work, is there a possibility to fix this in pure CSS?

Here's [a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AJ9hr/5/) of the scenario including a quick-and-dirty jQuery solution.

Answer (score 0):

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x3Pw6/6/)

HTML

```
  <div class='table'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='cell'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='cell'>
            <section></section>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='cell'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.table {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.row {
    display:table-row;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.row:first-child, .row:last-child {
    height:50px;
    background:black;
}
.cell {
    display:table-cell;
}
.cell:nth-child(2) {
    text-align:center;
    height:100%;
}
section {
    width:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    background:grey;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the content does not stretch to full height if there is less content: http://jsfiddle.net/x3Pw6/4/

Answer (score 0):

this is your css.nothing to change...just a few edit..

remove min-height,instead just height,and for id of section just give `height:100%`

```
html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}
#layout-helper-wrapper {
height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px auto;
    background-color: #eee;
    overflow: hidden;
}

header, footer {
    background-color: #fb2;
    margin: 0px;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
header {
    height: 30px;
}
footer {
    height: 20px;
    bottom: 0;
}

#body-wrapper {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 3px #aaa;
    padding: 30px 20px 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height:100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AJ9hr/11/

Comment: Looks cool, but the content is truncated if it exceeds screen height: http://jsfiddle.net/AJ9hr/12/

Answer (score 0):

I used this guy's method to make my footers stick to the bottom for pages that do NOT fill the viewport, but stay at the bottom of the page (not visible until scroll-down) when the content DOES fill the viewport.
Worked well for me with no additional edits/hacks.

http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/